# Override default get in javascript class such as __get in php

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, getter

I'm building a javascript library and I would like to be able to do exactly like the PHP's __get does.

My library has a `attributes` property which stores each model's attributes. Now, I am force to get an attribute using a `.get` method. But I would be able to do it with a getter. Let's says that User extends my model class.

```
let instance = new User({firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'});
console.log(instance.get('firstname')); // gives me 'John'
```

I want to be able to do `instance.firstname` which will call the `.get` method passing 'firstname' as parameter. In PHP you can do it that way : http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Is this something possible?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy using ES 2015 classes:

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this._bar = null;
  }

  get bar () {
    doStuff();
    return this._bar;
  }

  set bar (val) {
    doOtherStuff();
    this._bar = val;
    return this;
  }
};

var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = 3; // calls setter function
console.log(foo.bar); // calls getter function
```

here's the (simplified) output from babel:

```
var Foo = function () {
  function Foo() {
    this._bar = null;
  }

  _createClass(Foo, [{
    key: "bar",
    get: function get() {
      doStuff();
      return this._bar;
    },
    set: function set(val) {
      doOtherStuff();
      this._bar = val;
      return this;
    }
  }]);

  return Foo;
}();
```

Note that this isn't just for classes, any arbitrary object can have these:

```
var baz = {
  get qux() {
    // arbitrary code
  },
  set qux(val) {
    // arbitrary code
  }
};
```

[Source.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

## EDIT

---

What you want is possible but only in native ES 6 environments, as `Proxy` cannot be polyfilled.

```
var getter = function(target, property, proxy) {
  console.log(`Getting the ${property} property of the obj.`);
  return target[property];
};

var setter = function(target, property, value, proxy) {
  console.log(`Setting the ${property} property to ${value}.`);
  target[property] = value;
};

var emptyObj = {};

var obj = new Proxy(emptyObj, {
  get: getter,
  set: setter
});

obj.a = 3; // logs 'Setting the a property to 3'
var foo = obj.a; // logs 'Getting the a property of the obj'
```

Comment: I already know all of that. The thing is that properties are dynamics.
I want that `foo.bar` calls `foo.get('bar')` and that `foo.baz` calls `foo.get('baz')`, in short

Comment: @NicolasBoisvert updated. Its possible, but not very portable yet.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply assign the properties in a loop:

```
User = function (attrs) {
    for (var name in attrs) {
        this[name] = attrs[name];
    }
}

User.prototype = {
   // further methods
}
```

Using the ES6 class syntax, - I have to admit I do not see the point of writing things this way:

```
class User {
    constructor (attrs) {
        for (var name in attrs) {
            this[name] = attrs[name];
        }
    }

    // further methods
}
```

Remember: the second syntax is exactly what happens with the first one, only with some sugar on top.

Comment: I seen stuff like that, the thing is that attributes always change. What you suggest is, at the object creation, itterate through attribute to create getters?

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely, but if they are dynamic, well, why not? The properties object is a plain object; you can build it any way you want.

Comment: Ah. Now I see. You want to accomodate multiple attributes with one single function, while I was thinking about a getter function that could transform data before output. I'll change my example for your problem.

Comment: Here is the library I'm building if you want to see what I'm doing actually https://github.com/nicklayb/modelizejs

Comment: I've shortened my example a bit using the pattern found [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#_private-data-via-constructor-environments) and added the class syntax.

Comment: @ccprog this answer is unnecessarily complex, ES classes have getter/setter shorthand notation.

Comment: Screatch everything I have said. It doesn't even work this way. Old rule: do not define functions in loops. See another edit.